# laravel display data on a page based on id

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a page that shows links with name of businesses that are retrieved in database like this:

Controller:

```
public function viewBusiness() {
// Return our "website" object
$business = Business::all();
// Pass the contents of the "html" property to the view
return view('viewBusiness', ['business' => $business]);
}
```

View:

```
@extends('master') @section('title', 'Live Oldham') @section('content')
@section('content')
            @foreach ($business as $businesses)
        <a target="_blank" href="{{ url('business/' . $businesses->name) }}"> {{($businesses->name) }}
        </a> @endforeach       
@endsection
```

Route:

```
Route::get('business/list', 'BusinessController@viewBusiness')->name('viewBusiness');
```

I then have added a function where user click on a link and it is taken to a page which displays all data for that specific business, however it diplays all data but for all businesses.

Controller:

```
function displayBusiness() {
    $business = Business::all();
    $address = Address::all();
    return view('displayBusiness', ['business' => $business, 'address' => $address]);
}
```

View:

```
@foreach ($business as $businesses)
    <p>{{$businesses->name}}</p>
    <p>{{$businesses->email}}</p>
@endforeach
@foreach ($address as $addresses)
    <p>{{$addresses->firstline_address}}</p>
    <p>{{$addresses->secondline_address}}</p>
    <p>{{$addresses->town}}</p>
    <p>{{$addresses->city}}</p>
    <p>{{$addresses->postcode}}</p>
    <p>{{$addresses->telephone}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Route:

```
Route::get('business/{name}', 'BusinessController@displayBusiness')->name('displayBusiness');
```

Now here's the question, how can this code be modified so only a business that match either bussiness->name or business->id is displayed. (I guess name is taken when user clicks on a name.

Another question is how to restrict the url so that if localhost/business/{name} is not equal to any business->name in the database returns error? at the moment it shows the page no matter what you enter.

Thanks!

Comment: About your second question, You are not using any parameter inside the displayBusiness function so it returns all data whatever you sent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if I understood the question, but that may be the beginning of a solution ...

First view :

```
@extends('master') @section('title', 'Live Oldham')
@section('content')
            @foreach ($business as $businesses)
        <a target="_blank" href="{{ url('business/' . $businesses->id) }}"> {{($businesses->name) }}
        </a> @endforeach       
@endsection
```

Second Controller :

```
function displayBusiness($id) {
    $business = Business::find($id);
    $address = Address::find($id);
    return view('displayBusiness', compact('business', 'address'));
}
```

Second View :

```
    <p>{{$business->name}}</p>
    <p>{{$business->email}}</p>
    <p>{{$address->firstline_address}}</p>
    <p>{{$address->secondline_address}}</p>
    <p>{{$address->town}}</p>
    <p>{{$address->city}}</p>
    <p>{{$address->postcode}}</p>
    <p>{{$address->telephone}}</p>
```

Second Route :

```
Route::get('business/{id}', 'BusinessController@displayBusiness')->name('displayBusiness');
```

Comment: This works but I want to show business name in url instead of id, however I want the search to use business id, is that possible?

Comment: Ok, in this case you will need to generate a slug of the name with the method str_slug($name) and have a slug column in the database. Next, replace $id by $slug and query your model with `$business = Business::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();`

Comment: where should the method str_slug go? do I need to install something in order to use that?

Comment: In your controller just add `$business->slug = str_slug($name);` and create column **slug** in your table businesses, str_slug method generate a Semantic URL for what you want (name, description)

Comment: and nothing else has to be added? that will then change the url?

Comment: Replaces only all id fields in my example with slug fields and normally everything should be ok

Comment: For your second controller  `function displayBusiness($slug) {
    $business = Business::where('slug', '=', $slug)->get();
    return view('displayBusiness', compact('business'));
}` After I think you would need business to address relationships but it makes things a little more complicated :) [Laravel Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: I've got a relationship between these tabels ;)

Answer (score 0):

Route parameters are available in the controller function as parameters. Now you can build a query with this function. If your query does not return any results, you can send the user back to the business overview.

```
function displayBusiness($name) {
    $business = Business::where('name', $name)->orWhere('id', $name)->first();
    if ($business === null)
    {
        // No business with this name or id found.
        // Redirect to businesses list page.
    }

    $address = Address::all();
    return view('displayBusiness', ['business' => $business, 'address' => $address]);
}
```

Comment: I get: Trying to get property of non-object